# jQuery child selector not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, nested

here's my markup:

```
<div class=widget>
    <div class=panel>panel1</div>
    <div class=panel>panel2
        <div class=widget>
            <div class=panel>panel1</div>
            <div class=panel>panel2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i'm trying to select only the DIRECT (first level?) children with classname `panel`, unfortunately i keep getting always the nested elements (4 instead of 2).

please take a look at my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Jf/

what's wrong? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two parent `div`s with the same class.  Change your HTML to this to get the behavior you want:

```
<div class=widget1>
    <div class=panel>panel1</div>
    <div class=panel>panel2
        <div class=widget2>
            <div class=panel>panel1</div>
            <div class=panel>panel2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your script to this:

```
var panels = $("div.widget1 > .panel");
alert(panels.length); // returns 2

var panels = $("div.widget2").children(".panel");
alert(panels.length); // returns 2
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Jf/2/))

Answer (score 2):

you have  more than one parents div with class widget.
But for example you can try to select first div with class widget

```
var panels = $("div.widget:first > .panel");
alert(panels.length); // returns 2

var panels = $("div.widget:first").children(" >.panel");
alert(panels.length); // returns 2
```

You can change class widget of the second div to separate count

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Jf/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var panels = $("div.widget > div.panel:first-child");
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9sFmV/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `>`:

```
$("div.widget").find(" > .panel:first-child");
```

Your div's have the same class and so that will return all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var panels = $("div.widget").children().find("div.panel");
alert(panels.length); // returns 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected the problem is that it is gettin every div with class widget and since you have got 2 widget classes with 2 panel classes each, then that is why you get a count of 4 and that is why it alerts all of them

Answer (score 1):

I Don't get it.. what are you trying to get - the last child or the first ?

What do you mean by DIRECT children .. the first ?

```
$("div.widget .panel:first");
   // OR
   $(".widget .panel").find("widget")
```

Is that helpful ? :)